# How do I deactivate all the virtual buttons in Vuforia after pressing just one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Good afternoon!

I'm trying to make a simple AR quiz game that requires virtual buttons to answer. The game goes on if the correct button is pressed.

The question is: **how do I deactivate all the virtual buttons when a virtual button is pressed**? 
I've looked at nearly every topic regarding this, but can't figure it out how to make this work.
At this point I can press all the buttons but only once.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for my bad English)!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class PushToDebug : MonoBehaviour, IVirtualButtonEventHandler
{
public string vbName;
public AudioSource audi;


void Start()
{
    //Register with the virtual buttons TrackableBehaviour
    VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vrb = GetComponentsInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
    audi = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    for (int i = 0; i < vrb.Length; i++)
        vrb[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
}

public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{
    vbName = vb.VirtualButtonName;

        if (vbName == "VB1")
        {
         Debug.Log("Button 1 is pressed!");
         audi.Play();
         vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;

        }

        else if (vbName == "VB2")
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 2 is pressed!");
            audi.Play();
            vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;
        }

        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 3 is pressed!");
            audi.Play();
            vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;
        }
}


public void OnButtonReleased(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
    {
        if (vbName == "VB1")
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 1 is released!");
        }

        else if (vbName == "VB2")
        {
         Debug.Log("Button 2 is released!");
        }

        else
        {
        Debug.Log("Button 3 is released!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your reply! 
For some weird reason it doesn't just work.

I added `Debug.Log("DeactivateButtons is called!");` and this method wasn't called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are disabling only one button when pressed whereas others remain active. You can add a function to check if any of the buttons are pressed so that you can deactivate them.
Or since you are finding the name of the button when pressed, then you can probably create 3 variables such as:

```
var VB1 = GameObject.Find("VB1");
var VB2 = GameObject.Find("VB2");
var VB3 = GameObject.Find("VB3");
if(VB1 != null && VB2 != null && VB3 != null){

    VB1.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
    VB2.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
    VB3.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
}
```

Now to integrate the above to your code, perhaps under `OnButtonPressed()` function; you can add:

```
public void OnButtonPressed(VirtualButtonBehaviour vb)
{
    vbName = vb.VirtualButtonName;

        if (vbName == "VB1")
        {
         Debug.Log("Button 1 is pressed!");
         audi.Play();
         vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;
         DeactivateButtons();

        }

        else if (vbName == "VB2")
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 2 is pressed!");
            audi.Play();
            vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;
            DeactivateButtons();
        }

        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Button 3 is pressed!");
            audi.Play();
            vb.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehaviour>().enabled = false;
            DeactivateButtons();
        }
}

public void DeactivateButtons()
{
   var VB1 = GameObject.Find("VB1");
   var VB2 = GameObject.Find("VB2");
   var VB3 = GameObject.Find("VB3");
   if(VB1 != null && VB2 != null && VB3 != null){

      VB1.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
      VB2.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
      VB3.GetComponent<VirtualButtonBehavior>().enabled = false;
   }
}
```